# Period of a continuous signal

Tags: continuous-signals, periodic

So I have 
$$x_1=2 \cos(.6\sqrt\pi x+\pi/6)$$ and $$x_2= \sin(1.2\sqrt\pi x-\pi/3)$$ and need to find the period of $(x_1+x_2)^2$.

Let $$a=.6\sqrt\pi x+\pi/6 ~~~\text{and} ~~~ b=1.2\sqrt\pi x-\pi/3$$ so that 
$$x_1=2 \cos(a) ~~ \text{and} ~~ x_2=\sin(b).$$

And finally we get: 
$$(x_1+x_2)^2=1.5+2\cos(2a)+2\sin(a+b)+2\sin(a-b)-.5\cos(2b)$$

Now, the how do I calculate the time period of it?

Edit:

$$\text{period of the individul sinusoids in the square}~~T_1=5\sqrt\pi/3 ~~ T_2=10\sqrt\pi/9~~T_3=10\sqrt\pi/3 ~~ T_4=5\sqrt\pi/6 $$

$$\text{The ratios are}~~T_4/T_3=1/4~~T_4/T_2=3/4~~T_4/T_1=1/2$$

$$\text{LCM of denominators is 4 } $$

$$\text{Hence period }~~T=4T_4=10\sqrt\pi/3$$
is that correct?

Comment: This a homework type problem so you would need to show us where exactly you're stuck. You've computed the square, but haven't shown any attempt to figure out the period.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_0$ be the period of the signal  $s(t) = x_1(t) + x_2(t)$.
$$s(t) = s(t+T_0) \tag{1}$$

Then the period for $s^2(t) = ( x_1 + x_2)^2$ will be either $T_0$ or $T_0/2$ :

First, it's obvious that $T_0$ is also a period for $s(t)^2$ as it satisfies $$s^2(t) = s^2(t+T_0) \tag{2}$$

However, $T_0 / 2$ **may** also be period for $s^2(t)$. Since we are looking for the smallest number to satisfy eq(2).

Hence do the following:

1. Find the period $T_0$ of $s(t) = x_1(t)+x_2(t)$.
2. Check if $T_0/2$ satisfies $s^2(t) = s^2(t+T_0)$.
3. If yes; then period of $s^2(t)$ is $T_0/2$; otherwise $T_0$.

Comment: @John  Hi! Have you tried the approach I have outlined ? Will you accept an answer ? or leave the question floating ? Don't forget to upvote as well :-))

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hint since your question is a classic homework problem. Note that a sum of sinusoids is periodic if you can write it in the following form:

$$x(t)=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \cos(2\pi kf_0t+\phi_k)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_k \sin(2\pi kf_0t+\varphi_k)$$

where $f_0$ is the fundamental frequency, and $T=1/f_0$ is the corresponding period. Note that even if $a_1=b_1=0$, $f_0$ can still be the fundamental frequency. I trust that you can take it from here.